# android studio won't show device when trying to run app (on Mac)

Tags: android

Is anyone else having a difficult time getting their device when running an application in Android Studio on a Mac.

Nexus 6 settings:

- USB debugging: turned on
- USB computer connection: Tried both 'Media device (MTP)' "Lets you transfer media files on Windows, or using Android File Transfer on Mac)" as well as to Camera (PTP) Lets you transfer photos using camera software, and transfer any files on computers that don't support MTP.
  -Android version: 5.1.1

I also attempted on my 2013 Nexus 7 running Android 5.0.2

---

In an attempt to troubleshoot I also tried setting an environment variable for tracing and received the error **cannot bind 'tcp: 5037'**

./adb kill-server

set ADB_TRACE=all

./adb nodaemon server

Comment: Try this: Connect device and in Device Manager install manually ADB drivers for the device, but no let that Windows search the driver, click in "Let me pick from a list" and search the ADB driver if this is installed, Windows would be replace it with the ADB and this would works.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, this is on a Mac. I just updated the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm happy to report back after two weeks of troubleshooting and talking with the Android Studio team I have fixed this issue with a simple factory reset of the Macbook Pros' OS.